scala abstract class with generic types and methods with boxed arguments - type mismatch
I am having trouble getting this Scala 2 code to compile:
import chisel3._
import circt.stage.ChiselStage.emitCHIRRTL

class Box[X](val content: X)
abstract class Combination[I <: Bits, O <: Bits] {
  def fn1: I => O
  def fn2: Box[I] => I
}

object Comb1 extends Combination[SInt, SInt] {
  def fn1 = (x: SInt) => x
  def fn2 = (x: Box[SInt]) => x.content
}

object Comb2 extends Combination[UInt, UInt] {
  def fn1 = (x: UInt) => x
  def fn2 = (x: Box[UInt]) => x.content
}

val rand = new scala.util.Random
val temp = rand.nextInt(2) + 1
val comb = temp match {
  case 1 => Comb1
  case 2 => Comb2
}

class TopModule[I <: Bits, O <: Bits](comb: Combination[I, O]) extends Module

println(emitCHIRRTL(new TopModule(comb)))


However, the error I get is the following:
type mismatch;
 found   : Playground.Combination[_ >: chisel3.SInt with chisel3.UInt <: chisel3.Bits with chisel3.Num[_ >: chisel3.SInt with chisel3.UInt <: chisel3.Bits], _ >: chisel3.SInt with chisel3.UInt <: chisel3.Bits with chisel3.Num[_ >: chisel3.SInt with chisel3.UInt <: chisel3.Bits]]{def fn2: Playground.Box[chisel3.SInt] with Playground.Box[chisel3.UInt] => chisel3.Bits}
 required: Playground.Combination[chisel3.Bits with chisel3.Num[_ >: chisel3.SInt with chisel3.UInt <: chisel3.Bits],chisel3.Bits with chisel3.Num[_ >: chisel3.SInt with chisel3.UInt <: chisel3.Bits]]

This example is available on Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JersAqMWRAC3Zgykbewr5A
Can anyone help me understand why this happens? I realize that this somehow the effect of including fn2, which uses the Boxed argument. Thus if I remove fn2 instances this code compiles fine.
My goal is to use Combination to parameterize the the TopModule and other similar classes.

While SInt and UInt both are subtypes of Bits, they are incompatible with each other. When you pattern match between Comb1 and Comb2, the result has to be assigned a type, but Scala can't determine a common supertype that satisfies both because fn2 expects Box[SInt] or Box[UInt]. This mismatch caused the error.
To resolve that, I used path-dependent types in the Combination class and it worked well here.
import chisel3._
import circt.stage.ChiselStage.emitCHIRRTL
import chisel3.util._
import chisel3.experimental.VecLiterals._ 


class Box[X](val content: X)
abstract class Combination{
  type I <: Bits
  type O <: Bits
  def fn1: I => O
  def fn2: Box[I] => I
}

object Comb1 extends Combination {
  type I = SInt
  type O = SInt
  def fn1 = (x: I) => x
  def fn2 = (x: Box[I]) => x.content
}

object Comb2 extends Combination {
  type I = UInt
  type O = UInt
  def fn1 = (x: I) => x
  def fn2 = (x: Box[I]) => x.content
}

val rand = new scala.util.Random
val temp = rand.nextInt(2) + 1


val comb: Combination = temp match {
  case 1 => Comb1
  case 2 => Comb2
}

class TopModule(val comb: Combination) extends Module

println(emitCHIRRTL(new TopModule(comb)))

